# GitLab CI, How to make sure job execute only if the previous job did?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have 2 stages with multiple jobs and the jobs in the first stage have some rules that tell them if the need to run or not, so what I am trying to do is to tell some of the jobs in the second stage to execute only if the relevant job in the first stage ran.
I don't want to use the same rules I used for the first stage job to prevent conflicts.
Is there a way to do that?

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

Build0:
    stage: build
    extends:
        - .Build0Rules
        - .Build0Make

Build1:
    stage: build
    extends:
        - .Build1Rules
        - .Build1Make

Deploy0:
    stage: deploy
    dependencies:
        - Build0
    script:
        - bash gitlab-ci/deploy0.sh

Deploy1:
    stage: deploy
    dependencies:
        - Build1
    script:
        - bash gitlab-ci/deploy1.sh
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot specify that a job should be added to the pipeline if another job was added to the pipeline. Each job can specify whether it is added to the pipeline using `only`/`except` conditions or `rules`, but these are not able to reference other jobs.

It is possible to generate a pipeline yaml file and then trigger it, but I think this would not be ideal because of the amount of work involved.

```
stages:
 - Build
 - Deploy

build:
 stage: Build
 script:
   - do something...
 artifacts:
   paths:
     - deploy-pipeline-gitlab-ci.yml

deploy:
 stage: Deploy
 trigger:
   include:
     - artifact: deploy-pipeline-gitlab-ci.yml
       job: build
   strategy: depend
```

I would recommend using similar `only`/`except` conditions or `rules` on each job to build the pipeline that you want.

Comment: Yeah, it's a shame that you cannot generate a dependency on adding a job depending on another job execution.

I will like that the `needs` setup imported or inherit the `rules:`/`only:`/`except:` settings of the previous mandatory job.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. You should check the keyword `needs` that allow to do what you want: execute a job based on the execution of other jobs, ignoring stages order.

The documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs

Here is also an exemple of how to build a DAG (direct acrylic graph) using `needs`: https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/12/10/basics-of-gitlab-ci-updated/#directed-acyclic-graphs-get-faster-and-more-flexible-pipelines

In your case:

```yaml
Deploy0:
    stage: deploy
    needs: ["Build0"]
    script:
        - bash gitlab-ci/deploy0.sh

Deploy1:
    stage: deploy    
    needs: ["Build1"]
    script:
        - bash gitlab-ci/deploy1.sh
```

Note you can also specify multiple jobs in the `needs` command:

```yaml
needs: ["build0", "test0", "test1"]
```

Comment: In GitLab 13.9 and older, if needs refers to a job that might not be added to a pipeline because of only, except, or rules, the pipeline might fail to create

Comment: If you have `rules`, `except` or `only` settings in the mandatory/first job this may not work, and it will even fail with some error similar to `yaml invalid` : Found errors in your .gitlab-ci.yml: `'Deploy0' job needs 'Build0' job, but 'Build0' is not in any previous stage.`

Answer (score 0):

you can reference rules from other jobs:

```
job1:
  stage: test
  image: "****rhel8image****"
  script:
    - echo "XXX" > artifact.txt
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED == "true"

job2:
  stage: test
  image: "****rhel8image****"
  needs:
    - job1
  script:
    - cat artifact.txt
  rules:
    - !reference [job1, rules]
```